# JSON - Why serialize and send data?

Tags: javascript, json

JSON data is of 2 forms, object form and string form. It says that JSON is used to serialize data and send it across the network. Serialize means stringifying tht data and sending across. My questions is - Is there a need to stringify the data and send it only? Why not send the JSON object across, isn't this possible? Is there any advantage of stringifying and sending?

Comment: QUestion is based on a fundamental misunderstanding of how data is transferred. Also there is no such thing as a JSON object, JSON by definition is string

Comment: What is "object form" of JSON?

Answer (score 5):

There are no "advantages" to serializing, it's *required*. You can't send objects across the network. They need to be converted into a sequence of bytes and reconstituted on the other end.

> Why not send the JSON object across, isn't this possible?

No, it's not. In fact, there is no such thing as a "JSON object" in the first place. JSON is a *textual* representation of data. An in-memory object is not JSON, even if it was declared in source-code using the same characters that you might use to write JSON, or if it started out as a JSON document.

JSON is text.  The string of characters `'{ "x" : "y" }'` is JSON. Once your browser has evaluated it, it is not JSON, it is a JavaScript object.

Comment: So serialization does mean stringifying it, right? As in the JSON.stringify()

Comment: Serialization is the process of converting an object to a sequence of bytes. JSON is a format to which you can serialize objects.

Answer (score 2):

What does "a JSON object" look like on the wire? ... I'll wait...

The answer is that "objects" and such are complex data structures which live in a computer's memory and are often only meaningful while they're in this state. If you want to take them out of memory and store them on disk or send them across a network, you need to put them in a specified format which can be read again on the other end. That's what serialisation is. JSON is one possible serialisation format which can represent somewhat complex data structures, including arrays and objects. There are other such formats for many different purposes, ranging from XML to binary dumps specific to a certain language or environment.

Answer (score -1):

give socket.io a try..
I love it..
    /// Server
    socket.send("myMSG", {key1:"HelloWorld"});

```
/// Client  
socket.on("myMSG", function(data){
    console.log(data.key1);
});

// stringify
JSON.stringify({key1: "HelloWorld"})
```

Best Regards